# Minimising a linear function with a regularizer

Tags: optimization

I have the following optimization problem.

$$\underset{w}{\text{minimize}} \ w^\intercal x + \lambda \|w\|^2$$

I am told to solution is:

$$w = -2 \lambda x$$

Why?

Also scribbled on the paper is

$$x + \lambda w = 0$$

Comment: Which norm are you using? The $2$-norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A huge thank you to @JeanMarie and @Alex R for getting me 99% of the way there.

The solution is:

$$w= \frac{x}{- 2 \lambda} $$

The $ \lambda $, at least for my problem,is very important.

Answer (score 3):

Just differentiate in each component of $w$. You get:

$$x_i+2w_i=0.$$

From which it follows that $w_i=-x_i/2$. Now verify this is a minimum

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the value of $w$ which minimizes this expression, there is a [general result](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/exa_quad_fcn_cvx_min.html) that says that the quadratic expression (with $A$ definite positive) :

$X^TAX+X^TB+c$ is minimized when its gradient is 0, i.e.,

$2AX+B=0$ which is equivalent to say that $X$ is the unique solution to $AX=-\frac{1}{2}B$.

Here $A=I$, $B=w$, thus the answer is $X=-\frac{1}{2}w$.

Comment: Thanks. Where does \lambda come into this?

Comment: It is of no use. One could think that the proposed dolution comes from considering this problem as a minimization under constraints with $\lambda$ a Lagrange multiplier...

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am still confused. I am looking for w but the solution is -0.5 * w?